# NullPointerException is thrown when trying to set an Adapter in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, adapter

*(I already posted a question about this problem that got deleted. I am sorry if I didn't explained my problem good enough. Also I am a german person so forgive me if my english isn't very good.)*

I really tried a lot of things to get this simple program to work. I think that the solution to this will be very simple but first you need to find it...
I tried three different ways to code this and ended up with this one based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-_hKWMA7mk) Tutorial:

1. Define the Variable

   `String[] list = {"One", "Two", "Three"};`
2. Creating the Adapter

   `ListAdapter Adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);`
3. Cast the ListView into the View

   `ListView mainList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList1);`
4. Set the Adapter (wish causes the problem)

   `mainList1.setAdapter(Adapter1);`

So everytime I am trying to set the Adapter the Program throws out a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. As I already said I tried a lot of things to get this program to work. This is why I now need the help of the StackOverflow-Comunity. I am trying to explain this problem as good as I can so maybe one day I can finish my project...

**These information's might also be relevant to this:**

Full `MainActivity.java` *(Original)*:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        String[] Vertretung1 = {
                "1. Stunde | Frie [Ku] --› Eshk [Et Raum 008]",
                "2. Stunde | Frie [Ku] --› Eshk [Et Raum 008]",
                "3. Stunde | Frie [Ku] --› Eshk [Et Raum 008]"
        };

        String[] Vertretung2 = {
                "1. Stunde | Grok [Ma] --› Grot [De Raum 111]",
                "2. Stunde | Grok [Ma] --› Grot [De Raum 111]",
                "3. Stunde | Grok [Ma] --› Grot [De Raum 111]"
        };

        ListAdapter Adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Vertretung1);

        ListView mainList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList1);

        mainList1.setAdapter(Adapter1); //Causes the Problem

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }


    }

    public static class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_one, container, false);


            return rootView;
        }

    }

    public static class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_two, container, false);


            return rootView;
        }

    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentOne();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentTwo();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "HEUTE";
                case 1:
                    return "MORGEN";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Full `activity_main.xml` *(Original)*:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="me.muehl.cvovertretungsplan.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Full `fragment_main_one.xml` *(Original)*: [link][2]
```

Thanks for reading ;)

Comment: please include the necessary code inside your question and not as a link, since the link can get invalid.

Comment: It's not unexplainable... Your Activity xml doesn't have a ListView with the id you are trying to find

Comment: write that setting adapter and listview code in `FragmentOne` fragment as listview exists in that fragment layout.

Comment: [link to the 2. xml](http://pastebin.com/dgurMNQ1)  (cant edit the post)

Comment: too old question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move all ListView things into the Fragment class instead of the activity since that is where you've defined the ListView in the XML.

```
ListView mainList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList1);
```

That line will search only in the layout you've used in `setContentView`.

---

In order to move the ListView in the Fragment, you can find this line

```
View view = inflater.inflate...
```

And get the ListView with the next lines containing...

```
ListView lv = view.findViewById(...);
// TODO: setAdapter 
return view;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out...